# Google Cloud Endpoints : Picturesque App

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am currently learning Google App Engine. I want to develop a cloud app that provides synchronization using Google Cloud Endpoints. Frankly, I am impressed with Picturesque App (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-picturesque-python) that was demonstrated during Google I/O 2013. This app shows the feature that I really need.

To try out the application, I cloned it from GitHub and ran it through Google App Engine Launcher then when I tested it, there was no synchronization happened there. All pictures were saved locally. I already created and configured "settings.py" file with my Client ID as well as a  "custom-js/picturesque-config.js" however I could not see Client-Server interaction in the app. Everything seemed to work locally.

I also got a problem with the google authentication. There was an error written there "Error: origin_mismatch" with all the requests details. I have been trying to fix this problem for a week but still, it could not work as expected. Could anyone shed some light on this issue? Herewith, I list the information on the requests details.

```
    from_login=1
    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read
    redirect_uri=postmessage
    state=519184294|0.3676346342
    origin=http://localhost:22080
    as=-5faa3d6126cb2118
    display=page
    request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity
    hl=en-GB
    cookie_policy_enforce=false
    response_type=code token id_token gsession
    access_type=online
    cookie_policy=single_host_origin
    proxy=oauth2relay412480175
    include_granted_scopes=true
    client_id=604391723960.apps.googleusercontent.com
    authuser=0
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an OAuth problem and the synchronization can't work if you can't sign in.

As the error says, you have an "Origin Mismatch".

What are the "Redirect URIs" for your application ID in the APIs console? The URI you are using -- e.g. `http://localhost:8080` -- must match exactly, port, HTTP scheme and trailing slash.

You should try to fix this error by checking out existing answers on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error%3A+origin_mIsmatch